# Is it possible to modify the attribute names used by the emulated view encapsulation

Tags: javascript, css, angular

is it possible in angular(2+) to modify or define rules for the attribute names used by the emulated view encapsulation.

**HTML:**

```
<hero-details _nghost-pmm-5>
  <h2 _ngcontent-pmm-5>Mister Fantastic</h2>
  <hero-team _ngcontent-pmm-5 _nghost-pmm-6>
    <h3 _ngcontent-pmm-6>Team</h3>
  </hero-team>
</hero-detail>
```

**CSS:**

```
[_nghost-pmm-5] {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
h3[_ngcontent-pmm-6] {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #777;
}
```

So for example `_nghost-pmm-5` would be `_nghost-xyz-5` or something I could define?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a posible solution that implies modifying the core code of the @angular dependency: Manually updating the content of `CONTENT_ATTR` variable.

Locate the files under:

- node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/@angular/
- node_modules/@angular/compiler/@angular/

Then search/replace its value for the desired one. That variables are used when angular compiles the application.

However, keep in mind that removing or updating your dependencies by using `npm-install` will replace all your changes.

It is working fine for me in a dev environment but I can't ensure this will work on production.